# How can I delete a hidden folder?

Tags: bash, shell, rm, dot-files

I want to delete many configuration folder in my home user folder but I can't figure out how to delete them. How can I delete a hidden folder?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can remove hidden directories (with `.` at the beginning of the name) like normal directories:

```
rm -rf .directory_name
```

(`r` for recursive, `f` for force).

To display hidden directories use `-a` option for `ls`:

```
ls -a
```

You can also use `mc` or some other file manager to remove them. Most of them will have option to display hidden directories in View menu or in settings. In `mc` hidden directories are displayed by default.

Comment: Better not to get in the habit of using `-f`. You should really only use it if you're expecting many read-only files (e.g. in a `.svn` folder).